# Is there any API available for digital signature of UAE PASS

Tags: java, digital-signature

I am looking for API or JAVA SDK to digitally sign any document using UAE PASS but unable to find any.
If anyone has already integrated with UAE Pass they can please share some ideas or knowledge.

[UAE PASS PORTAL](https://www.smartdubai.ae/apps-services/details/uae-pass)

Comment: Questions such as this one are actually explicitly off topic in this place.

Answer (score 1):

https://selfcare.uaepass.ae/developers

Have you checked this site? This has the integration details about UAE Pass.

Comment: Yes, I have already checked this, but they do not have any APIs exposed